# How to ignore typings-field when not using TypeScript in PhpStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, ecmascript-6, phpstorm, webstorm

In JetBrains PhpStorm 2019.3, I use JavaScript ES6.
Now, if I install e.g. [Foundation for Sites](https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/tree/v6.6.1) and use it with the following code in a file called main.js:

```
import {Dropdown, DropdownMenu, Accordion} from 'foundation-sites';
```

When  <kbd>CTRL + click</kbd> on `'foundation-sites'`, PhpStorm sends me to :

> node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.d.ts

even though I do not use TypeScript. The expected behaviour would be jumping to:

> node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.es6.js

I can change this behaviour by changing the `typings` field in the foundation-sites [package.json](https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/blob/v6.6.1/package.json#L8):

```
-  "typings": "dist/js/foundation.d.ts",
+  "typings": "dist/js/foundation.es6.js",
```

However, changing package.json fields in third party code just to fix PhpStorm moving to the wrong file seems inconvenient. How can I make PhpStorm ignore TypeScript references and fields when not using TypeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to tell the IDE to ignore `typings` field - it uses the TypeScript definition files to power its code completion for library methods. Normally it uses the following rules for navigation:

- If type definitions are installed in the `node_modules/@types` folder, IDE tries to navigate to the JavaScript sources of the library when using `Ctrl+click`. Please note that this only works for symbols that are defined as classes, variables or functions (and not interfaces or types) in the `.d.ts` file.
- If type definitions are available inside the module, IDEA does not index the JavaScript source by default and, thus, can't navigate to them. To index these files, you need choosing **Include Javascript Files** from module folder right-click menu.

The worse thing is that, though the `foundation-sites` bundles typings with it, these typings are not correct (see https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/issues/11653 and linked tickets), so IDEA can't map the ES6 imports to interfaces from `foundation.d.ts`.

The only workaround I can think of is commenting out the `"typings": "dist/js/foundation.d.ts",` in `package.json` - IDEA will then use declarations from `foundation.es6.js` for both completion and navigation